# Different URLs in debug and release -iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to set an url string different based on the build mode (release and debug).
I've defined an User-defined var in the build settings of the Target, and try to access it like this:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"SERVER_URL"];
```

But is returning null. What's the correct way of doing this?
I'm using Objective-c.

Comment: see this for help https://qualitycoding.org/production-url/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two [targets](https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/) with each one with its own [Preprocessor Macros](https://wpguru.co.uk/2013/06/how-to-define-preprocessor-macros-in-xcode/). For example you can create a **production** target with a Preprocessor Macro named `PRODUCTION`. So Every time you run with that target you will use *"PRODUCTION_URL"* otherwise you will use the *"DEVELOPMENT_URL"*.

So your code might look something like this:

```
#ifdef PRODUCTION
static NSString *const serverURL = @"PRODUCTION_URL";
#else
static NSString *const serverURL = @"DEVELOPMENT_URL";
#endif
```

### Swift

```
#if PRODUCTION
    static let serverURL = "PRODUCTION_URL"
#else
    static let serverURL = "DEVELOPMENT_URL"
#endif
```